# How to ignore S.M.A.R.T. error during El Capitan update?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, ssd

I have a disk with a S.M.A.R.T. error. In my particular case I know that it is relatively safe to continue to use my disk. I have error in SMART attribute #173 (wear level) but all those block overwrites happened in small volatile temp partition, my main system partition is safe. In short, I know what I'm doing.

I want to ignore this error and force the update. How to do that?

Comment: put it in a USB enclosure

Comment: Is it possible for MBPr late 2013? They have a small SSD card inside. I'm not sure whether it is compatible with SATA.

Comment: @Poma Wear leveling works by shuffling physical sectors of a storage device and mapping them to their fixed logical locations. You don't have a tiny section of your SSD worn out. It's the entire device as the sectors are non-contiguously mapped to the ICs.

Comment: @MaxRied anyways I have this SMART error for over a year and issues so far. And my whole SSD syncs with NAS every night.

Comment: If you have your engine light flashing red for the last year, would you go on a trip through the desert?

Answer (score 1):

I had that happen to me with a 2011 MacBook Pro. Apple told me that the only thing that could be done was to replace the hard drive.

Comment: Apple lied. I've already installed El Capitan with the help of disk imaging software.

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work for me. After the hard drive was replaced, it worked fine.

Comment: It costs ~$600 to replace 1Tb SSD and I don't want to pay that until it is actually broken

Comment: Oh ok lol yeah much more expensive with SSD. The one I diagnosed cost $100 to fix - including the price of the hard drive. But, yeah, at that price, I see why you're waiting.